# Install Gnome 3 from live CD

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome3

I downloaded the live CD image of Gnome 3 Fedora and burned it to a CD. Restarting Windows and booting from the CD, I'm up and running. I love everything about it, but how can I install it?

When using the Ubuntu live CD for example there is an Install icon on the desktop, but not in Gnome from what I can see.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where did you get it from?

Comment: I got it from gnome3.org

Comment: It didn't gave the option to install. And I belive that we can not install gnome-3 this way.
Only way is to install the OS which comes with gnome 3 Or upgrade the gnome packages to version 3.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only way!

Answer (score 4):

"Press the windows key, and type install. This should show you an icon that will allow you to install everything to your hard drive."

The application you might be looking for is called "Live installer".

Comment: Cool thanks! If anyone can confirm that this works, I'm accepting this answer. I went another way and installed Fedora 15 beta with GNOME3.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm,

I'm using openSUSE 11.4 with GNOME 2.32 default, and when I booted from the livecd, I run the 'Software Packages Update' not 'Yast2', then it fetched the needed updates and when I clicked Install updates, everything is installed on my HDD, and I'm working fine now with GNOME 3.0.1,
Thanks for gnome 3 developers!

Answer (score 1):

Since this isn't solved yet, I would like to add my two cents -

I had a GNOME version of Fedora LiveCD. Reading [this](http://www.linuxreaders.com/2010/09/install-fedora-from-live-cd-cli.html#.T_9NEvWLLIt) article, it's apparent that you *can* actually get the livecd to install. You have to run yum as root before you can get started, however:

```
yum install firstboot anaconda
```

Also, for some reason, you have to run this command before you can start anaconda, otherwise the installation process will crash after selecting your timezone:

```
xhost +
```

Running those two commands should get you started, so you can then run

```
anaconda
```

(also as root). That got me a little bit of the way, but once it partitioned my disk, anaconda would fail with something about not being able to read the packages. After much searching, it seems next to impossible to "install" gnome to a hard drive. (Or in this case, some version of Fedora liveCD.)